# dynamic listview with dynamic values in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hello i am new in android and i am developing one application in which data are display in listview. Listview contains one textview and spinner. But for specific condition for example if there is one Qualification field which have one or more choice which user want to select. So at that specific condition i must give multiple checkboxes. Data are pass through webservices. I am store that data in POJO. And i already develop for textview and spinner with use of inflater. But i am facing problem for that checkbox control. How i put dynamically checkboxes when perticular condition occure.  [image: Problem]

**Edit** I am create two separate XML files for that. I use following code for that check box XML file.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    for (int k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {   
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_brands, null);  
    }
}
```

But XML file is call only ones. while the values contains 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you follow the idea posted in the comments on Mike's answer.

But if you really want to create something programatically it can be done in this way.

```
CheckBox check1 = new CheckBox(YourClassName.this);
CheckBox check2 = new CheckBox(YourClassName.this);

...
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
 ll.setOrientation(1);

        ll.addView(check1,0);
        ll.addView(check2,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are already using a custom adapter of some sort and are inflating a view in the getView() of that adapter.  Now all you need to do is create another xml file with the check boxes as you want.  Based on your condition inflate the appropriate xml and init the text for the check boxes when needed.

For instance lets say you have an xml like this lets say it is called radio_buttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

OK then in your code use your condition to inflate this xml instead of your default xml.

You can grab the text from the radio buttons by doing view.findViewById(R.id.button1) and set the text.

Comment: Alternatively just have one list item layout which already contains the checkboxes but by default are hidden. Then simply 'show' them when needed.

Comment: Can you please give me idea how to create it when spacific condition is occurred? and where i put that code? i am create dynamic listview in using getview method.

Comment: Also possible, but I think the seperate xmls might be a bit cleaner, especially if working with a graphic designer.

Comment: just put it in your  getView method in your custom adapter

Comment: @hardikjoshi What the above commentators are trying to say is that create an xml with the check-boxes and everything. Now, before populating each row in the ListView, check for the condition. If the condition gets satisfied, then set the visibility of the checkBoxes to visible, otherwise keep them hidden.

Comment: @swayam i understand about that but i don't know how to create that checkboxes dynamically at specific condition. My checkboxes values are not fix its a dynamic it will be one or two or more. I don't know how to create programatically.

Comment: You do not need to create the checkboxes dynamically. The checkboxes will be there in the xml of the row. You will only need to change the text label of the checkbox when the particular condition is fulfilled and change its visibility to visible.

Comment: @hardikjoshi see the edited answer with a sample xml, past that I think you might need to review Android Development because the rest of the implementation is fairly basic.